# How can I have one index for two rows in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to have my Years as indices in my dataframe. But each year refers to two rows. How can I do that?

This is what I have:

```
       TYPE Jan Feb 
2019 -  A    1   2
2019 -  B    4  4.3
```

This is what I want:

```
       TYPE Jan Feb 
2019 -  A    1   2
        B    4  4.3
```

Comment: df.groupby('year').head() should groupby year column and `head()` will allow you to view it.

Comment: @amanb year is already an index.

Comment: If you want simple single level index, then you shouldn't do what you want, because I believe it requires you to change the second value to `''`. But if you want a MultiIndex with Year x Type then you'll get the above (just with TYPE in the Index)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to have your DataFrame have multiple Indexes, the year and your `Type` column.  Here is some documentation on [advanced indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html)

I think this code sample from that link is pretty relevant to your desired output

```
In [1]: arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
   ...:           ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
   ...: 

In [2]: tuples = list(zip(*arrays))

In [3]: tuples
Out[3]: 
[('bar', 'one'),
 ('bar', 'two'),
 ('baz', 'one'),
 ('baz', 'two'),
 ('foo', 'one'),
 ('foo', 'two'),
 ('qux', 'one'),
 ('qux', 'two')]

In [4]: index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])

In [5]: index
Out[5]: 
MultiIndex([('bar', 'one'),
            ('bar', 'two'),
            ('baz', 'one'),
            ('baz', 'two'),
            ('foo', 'one'),
            ('foo', 'two'),
            ('qux', 'one'),
            ('qux', 'two')],
           names=['first', 'second'])

In [6]: s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(8), index=index)

In [7]: s
Out[7]: 
first  second
bar    one       0.469112
       two      -0.282863
baz    one      -1.509059
       two      -1.135632
foo    one       1.212112
       two      -0.173215
qux    one       0.119209
       two      -1.044236
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a MultiIndex using an Index and a column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2019, 2019 ],'Type': ['A',' B'],'Jan': [1, 4,],'Feb': [2, 4.3]})
df = df.set_index(['year', 'Type'])
print(df)
```

Follow this resource for more detailed explanation
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html